# How to run pyinstaller correctly on cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I want to generate a .exe file from a python file but when i try to use pyinstaller I get an error "Python Library not found". I'm using python 2.7.10 and I'm using virtualenv as well. Should I type the path /usr/bin/python on the pyinstaller command or maybe the python path on the virtualenv?

EDIT: errors

```
16769 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-kernel32-private-l1-1-1.dll dependency of C:\Windows/system32/user32.dll
16910 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-privateprofile-l1-1-1.dll dependency of C:\Windows/system32/user32.dll
17413 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-privateprofile-l1-1-1.dll dependency of C:\Windows/system32/GDI32.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module> sys.exit(run())
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/main.py", line 88, in run
run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/main.py", line 46, in run_build
PyInstaller.build.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1924, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1873, in build
execfile(spec)
File "/home/paulo-desktop/github/cmd3test/cmd3/pyinstaller/shell.spec", line 6, in <module>
runtime_hooks=None)
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 446, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 309, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 677, in assemble
self._check_python_library(binaries)
File "/home/paulo-desktop/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 727, in _check_python_library
raise IOError("Python library not found!")
IOError: Python library not found!
(ENV)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use cygwin too and I encountered this issue as well. I re-ran the cygwin installer and just added the python installer from there. It will be there once you run the app again.

Comment: Did you add the pyinstaller from the cygwin setup?

Comment: Yes! It's part of the installer where you could add certain packages that you need. Paramiko, python, etc.

Comment: Oh and in that case should I add just the python package?

Comment: Yes sir. That should do it right there. Also you could check this: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/Installing-Python-inside-Cygwin

Comment: I tried and I still get the same error. I'll update my question with the errors

Comment: Did you install it from within Cygwin first? In this window: http://i.imgur.com/nuMxyKG.jpg

Comment: What's your processor? Did you make sure that the installer you downloaded is for your processor? (32bit/64bit)

Comment: Cool. Then it must be missing the DLLs that are needed. Check this out: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/32-bit-application-fails-to-start-after-81-upgrade/b825723e-e2a2-4c8f-bd1f-10446a5d7059?page=5

Comment: Just download and install the vcredist and you should be all set.

Comment: I think there might have been a misunderstanding here...pyinstaller vs python installer